# tradeoffs of different compression algorithms

Tags: compression, zip, gzip, bzip

What are the tradeoffs of the different compression algorithms?

The purpose is backup, transfer & restore. I don't care about popularity, as long as a mature enough tool exists for unix. I care about

- time
- cpu
- memory
- compression level

the algorithms I am considering are

- zip
- bzip
- gzip
- tar
- others?

Comment: tar is not a compression algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tar is not a compression algorithm per se.

You may use zip/gzip when time for compression/decompression is the most important issue.

You may use bzip when you need a better compression rate.

You may use LZMA when even bigger compression rate needed, but CPU time bigger.

[Have a look here](http://tukaani.org/lzma/benchmarks).

Comment: This comparison site is outdated, because there are lot of changes in lzma and 7zip since 2005.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to look at compression benchmark sites:

[Maximumcompression](http://www.maximumcompression.com)

[Compressionratings](http://www.compressionratings.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It usually depends on your input data but I've never found anything that gives me better general compression than 7zip (http://www.7-zip.org).

Answer (score 0):

It would be very simple to create a simple testbed for those cases.

Write a script that uses each in turn on a set of files that is representative of those you wish to comporess, and measure the time/cpu/memory usage/compression ratio acheived.

Rerun them a statistically significant number of times, and you'll have your answer.